# Accessing JNDI with Play 2.2

Tags: scala, jndi, playframework-2.2

I am trying to access a Datasource specified in the Tomcat server.xml and context.xml by 
play.
The playapplication is located as war within the tomcat webapps and also has the Connection in its web.xml specified with:

```
  <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/Testconnection</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

To see hat the connection is specified I used a jsp to check the configuration:

```
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
Context componentBindings = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) componentBindings.lookup("jdbc/Testconnection");
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
String connectionUrl = connection.getMetaData().getURL();
out.println(connectionUrl);
```

This showed the exspected result.
When trying to access the database within the play application it always results in:
"could not find datasource for ....: Token not allowed in path expression: '-'" pointing to the line containing `DB.withConnection` in my play app.

So what is confusing me is that there is not such a token as '-' within my whole code.

I tried to access the following combinations:

```
DB.withConnection("java:comp/env/jdbc/Testconnection") { imlicit c => .......}

DB.withConnection("java:jdbc/Testconnection") { imlicit c => .......}

DB.withConnection("jdbc/Testconnection") { imlicit c => .......}
```

Would be great if anybody can provide me with a solution or point me in the right direction.

Thank you very much!

**Solution:**

---

So the Solution (thanks to applicius!) could be:

import javax.naming.{Context, InitialContext}

import javax.sql.DataSource

[...]

var conn: java.sql.Connection  = (new InitialContext).lookup("java:/comp/env").asInstanceOf[Context].lookup("jdbc/Testconnection").asInstanceOf[DataSource].getConnection

val result: Option[Result] = SQL(queryName).on(("variable","replaceValue")).singleOpt(Result.rowMapper)(conn)

[...]

Comment: Where from is coming error `could not find datasource for ....: Token not allowed in path expression: '-'`? JSP? Your `withConnection` test (btw s/`imlicit`/`implicit`)?

Comment: Sorry that I were unclear on this. Edited my original post. The error is comming from the play application itself pointing to the `DB.withConnection` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play DB API is expecting a Play datasource name (one corresponding to entry in Play `application.conf`), not a JNDI name.

Either you get connection by your self using regular JNDI lookup and use it in your Play app (having to release it by yourself), or you move/duplicate datasource settings into Play config.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you perhaps be a little bit more specific about the regular JNDI lookup? Because duplicating the connection as entry in the application.conf is unfortunatly not an option for me.

Comment: Regular JNDI lookup = same as what you do in vanilla Java code (as in your test JSP: get `javax.sql.DataSource` from JNDI context, get `java.sql.Connection` from there. (BTW I suggest you file a pull request on Playframework GitHub repo asking for some `DBPlugin` based on JNDI).

Comment: Thank you applicius, for you help!

Comment: I think a JNDI `DBPlugin` could follow that --> https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3270#discussion_r15992234